# Polling MySQL database through Qt / QSqlTableModel (C++)

Tags: c++, sql, mysql, qt, polling

I'm using Qt to connect to a MySQL database (through QSqlTableModel / QSqlDatabase / etc) although this question is more general.

What's the best way to get a "live updating database table view"? One option would be to constantly poll the entire table (repeatedly calling the select() method in QSqlTableModel).
This seems inefficient though (is the entire table passed from MySQL to Qt each time?)

Another option would be to have another table, which acts as a log table (keeps track of all the updates / changes) and then you can poll this log table (checking only for new entries..which seems more efficient?). However, then you lose a lot of the QSql built in functionality).

Or should I have a counter variable that I poll, and then if that increases, I know to refresh the entire table?

All these approaches seem a bit messy.. what would you recommend? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a MySQL question but I have the answer! :)

What you want is in fact to poll the database every X seconds.  However, what will make this efficient is if you make a MySQL "trigger" so that if a row is inserted, updated, and/or deleted it will create an indicator.

I think you should create a trigger that will insert the modified row into a second table.  The poll from your Qt program should do these actions:

- lock the second "modifications" table
- read the entire contents of second "modifications" table
- delete all the contents of second "modifications" table
- unlock the second "modifications" table

If you dont lock the table you could accidentally delete an a new row that was inserted between reading and deleting.  However, if you want/need to avoid locking, just read everything, then delete the rows you retrieved based on a unique ID that is generated by each row insertion into the "modifications" table.

The FAQ and documentation for MySQL triggers is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html

Documentation for locking/unlocking tables is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html